# Which Eclipse base type should I install for ColdFusion Development?

Tags: windows-7, eclipse, coldfusion

When you use the `Eclipse Installer for Windows 7 32 bit` there is a screen with a list of options on which eclipse to install. I know eventually I will be adding the  `CFEclipse` add-on but I am not sure which base configuration to start with. Any info or direction would be much appreciated.

Below is a screen shot of the install list:
[image]

I am leaning towards the installation package for PHP since it has a lot of the HTML CSS XML stuff that is used in the ColdFusion view layer.

Comment: Can you include a screen cap of what you're looking at?

Comment: Please see my edit above. Thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheers for updating the question. I *thought* that's what you meant but wanted to be sure.

Just pick the top one: "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers". It's pretty much the baseline as far as I could determine, and unless you'll be using any of the other stuff the other installs offer: you don't need 'em.

You can always install them later if you need them anyhow.

If you're just doing CFML though, that'll do the trick.

As for the other mark-up oriented stuff you mention... you could indeed install the PHP bundle, but bear in mind that Eclipse is implemented *by design* as being plug-in centric, so there's no need to intrinsically settle for bundled stuff, you can go out and locate a subset of plug-ins that best suit you, and just install those. That said the ones that come with the PHP bundle could well be fine too. I guess it's a generic "web dev" combo.

Bear in mind that Adobe do their own Eclipse Plug-in: [ColdFusion Builder](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/coldfusion-builder.html). I find CFEclipse to be a bit primitive by comparison.

Also note that CFB does have a free version... just install the trial version (ie: without a licence key), and it will revert to the free licence after the trial period.